# What is the computational complexity of hyper-parameter tuning using grid seach?

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, grid-search

If I have numerous hyperparameters to tune, which can each be represented as vectors of arbitrary lengths e.g neuron number = `[4, 8, 16]`, learning rate = `[0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001]`, what would the computational complexity of a full grid search be?

Is it polynomial in number of different hyperparameters to tune?

Answer (score 2):

The full grid search would consider all possible cartesian product.

Suppose you have `k` lists with length `n1, n2, ..., nk`, then it would be `n1 x n2 x ... x nk`.

Hence, yes, it is polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is exponential because grid search is brute force (see [polynomial time](https://mathwiki.cs.ut.ee/asymptotics/05_polynomial_complexity)).

If you have `k` lists with length `n₁, …, nₖ` where `min(n₁, …, nₖ) = a > 1` then `T(k) = n₁ × n₂ × … × nₖ ∈ Ω(aᵏ)`.